# Why can't I access the htdocs directory through FTP?

Tags: ftp, hosting, directory-listing

While others are ok, FileZilla claims that it **Failed to retrieve directory listing** when accessing /var/www/htdocs.

The chmod is set to 775 for the htdocs directory.

I was transfering a folder with some php files to the htdocs dir when the connection broke. And then I've been unable to get to that dir since.

Comment: Could you please edit in more information? Else this question is likely to be closed as not being a real question. I'd suggest giving information on what you're trying to do or connect to and what your OS is.

Comment: @Eme can you please include "No, chmod's alright. 775 on the derectory (www is the parent)" and "I was transfering a folder with some php files to the htdoc dir when the connection broke. And then I've been unable to get to that dir." into your question please? That'd make this a much better question

Comment: @Earlz Like this :D?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions issue. FileZilla can list permissions. Goto the parent directory and see what the permissions list. It will look like 'drwxr-xr-x' or similiar. If the r's are missing that means you can't read the file.

Comment: No, chmod's alright. 775 on the derectory (www is the parent).

Comment: I was transfering a folder with some php files to the htdoc dir when the connection broke. And then I've been unable to get to that dir.